# How to use TComInterface properly?

Tags: com, c++builder

I would like to use TComInterface to replace raw pointer.

My current code is:

```c
{
TComInterface<IStoreNamespace> pStore;
if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_StoreNamespace, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IStoreNamespace, (LPVOID*)&pStore)))
    {
    if (SUCCEEDED(pStore->Initialize(Form1->Handle, 1)))
        {
        //pStore->CallOtherMethods...
        }
    }
// Release()'d automatically?
}
```

If I understood correctly this overwrites the pStore pointer with new pointer so it doesn't call `pStore->Release();` automatically from eventually previous instance using `pStore`.

Under what conditions is `Release()` called? I believe it may be when the variable goes out of scope even if I initialized it like this. And what is the proper way to initialize pStore in above example so it doesn't just overwrite pointer but also calls `Release()` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TComInterface` calls `Release()` on its internal interface when `TComInterface` goes out of scope and gets destructed.  You can also call the `TComInterface::Unbind()` method if you want to manually `Release()` the interface sooner.  `TComInterface` also calls `Release()` on its current interface if you assign a new interface pointer (or other `TComInterface` instance) via the `=` assignment operator.

`TComInterface` overrides the `&` operator to return a pointer to its internal interface, so you have to make sure that `TComInterface` is not holding an active interface before you call `CoCreateInstance()` (or anything else that will copy a new interface into `TComInterface`) or else the preview interface will be leaked and not released.  `TComInterface`'s default constructor sets the internal interface to NULL, so you don't usually have to worry about that, unless you re-use the same `TComInterface` variable multiple times, such as when using interface enumerators in a loop.

Comment: I understand but I guess what I was asking is how to do something like `TComInterface<IStoreNamespace> pStore = ???what here???` to initialize the pStore instead of calling `CoCreateInstance` and to automatically release/unbind previous value. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you already have a pre-existing interface pointer, using the `=` assignment operator works just fine to initialize the `TComInterface`. If you use the `=` operator when declaring the `TComInterface`, it will call the `TComInterface` constructor that takes an interface as input, and will store the interface pointer and call `AddRef()` on it (if it is not NULL). If you invoke the `=` operator later on the same `TComInterface`, it will `Release()` the existing interface (if it is not NULL), save the new interface pointer, and call `AddRef()` on it (if it is not NULL).

Comment: OK, so I can't actually initialize it the first time with `=` operator (or constructor?) but I have to use `CoCreateInstance` the very first time to obtain interface pointer, right?

Comment: `TComInterface` changes how you *MANAGE* an interface pointer, it does not change *WHERE* you get that interface pointer from (though it does have `CreateInstance()`, `ActiveInstance()`, and `RemoteInstance()` wrapper methods if you don't want to call `CoCreateInstance/Ex()` and `GetActiveObject()` directly). Interface pointers can come from any number of sources, not just from `CoCreateInstance()`.