# TComInterface is not calling Release

Tags: com, c++builder, typelib

I was tracking down an issue where "Outlook.exe" remains listed in TaskManager even though the Outlook Application object had been released and disposed by the TypeLibrary.

The calling Code is in C++ Builder.  **TComInterface** is used to instantiate the TypeLib.

What I noticed is that even though the Dialog Box (This is where the code is called from) is closed (user has clicked "Ok" or "Cancel") and the TComInterface object goes out of scope, "Release" is not called.

Release is never called until we exit the application entirely.

Is there another way to get TComInterface to call release when it goes out of scope?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057281/how-to-use-tcominterface-properly

Answer (score 1):

After digging some more, I found that the variable had global scope.

I changed the scope and now Release is being called.